# Magic Squares Print Square

Tags: java, magic-square

This is my print square method

```
public void printSquare()
{
  DecimalFormat newSquare = new DecimalFormat("00");
  for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)
  {
     for (int col = 0; col < square[row].length; col++)
     {  
        System.out.print((newSquare.format(square[row][col])) + " ");
     }
  }
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
```

}

this is what its output looks like

```
08 01 06 03 05 07 04 09 02
```

This is what i need it to look like

```
08 01 06

03 05 07

04 09 02
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a long time, any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Call `System.out.println` at the end of your inner loop?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but looks like you just need to move the `println()` calls inside the outer loop instead of after it.

Comment: Wow! Can't believe I missed this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add line break after each row

```
public void printSquare()
{
  DecimalFormat newSquare = new DecimalFormat("00");
  for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)
  {
     for (int col = 0; col < square[row].length; col++)
     {  
        System.out.print((newSquare.format(square[row][col])) + " ");
     }
     System.out.println(); // this will print new line after each row
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be fixed by using a `System.out.println("\n")` at the end of the outer loop

```
public void printSquare()
{
  DecimalFormat newSquare = new DecimalFormat("00");
  for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)
  {
     for (int col = 0; col < square[row].length; col++)
     {  
        System.out.print((newSquare.format(square[row][col])) + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("\n");
  }
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Their desired output looks like it's double spaced so would need `System.out.println("\n");`